# How to convert string “\uFFFF” to Unicode?

Tags: javascript, unicode

I am quite new to Javascript and easily get into trouble when dealing with string. I have done some research but it is difficult to get the solution and the best answer found in this site is in Java. I really need your help to make it in Javascript.

I started with this:

```
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlHttp.open("GET", sUrl, true);
xmlHttp.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=utf8');
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

The *xmlHttp.responseText* contains strings like `"le t\u00f9 di ch\u00e0o"` where the `\u00f9</b>` and `\u00e0` are Unicode characters (*ù*, *à*).

How can I covert the *xmlHttp.responseText* into readable characters in Javascript?

Comment: It looks like you're being sent a JSON-encoded string (it should have quotes around it). In this case, your MIME type should be "application/json" and you should `JSON.parse()` it.

Comment: what about server page code? does it encode data using utf8 charset?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thank you, it was what i received from the server.

Comment: @venkat7668 well, I can not read the page code because it is not mine, but it seems I can solve it now. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  **Niet the Dark Absol**'s hint, I solved the problem.

```
xmlHttp.overrideMimeType('application/json');
obj = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);

document.getElementById('Content').innerHTML = obj.data[0].name;
```

More info from
http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp